# How to compile & build ldcoe5viewer-PyQt5 on windows

Tags: python, windows, pyqt5

I used Linux for quite some time. building the ldoce5viewer on linux is well documented but in this github repo: https://github.com/purboo/ldoce5viewer-pyqt5 there is no information about building it for Windows. also I could not find any resources to do that. I need this dictionary on PC, so I appreciate a well documented guide on how to compile this package.

Comment: You'll need a c++ compiler, then start by a simple `make` in the project folder.

Comment: I really doubt about it. it is written in python and uses pyqt for gui. no c++

Comment: I know that it *uses* pyqt5, but the installation procedure uses a `Makefile` and the setup script clearly requires that. There are plenty of programs that use python bindings for the UI but actually have the backend using compiled sources. That said, building it *might not* be required, but you have to carefully read all the package contents and ensure that, then manually do all required steps that the Makefile does. Btw, even if you succeed, this will *not* "install" the program, it will only allow you to run it. Btw, see https://askubuntu.com/q/1066766 and https://askubuntu.com/q/1237337